# How to prevent css class to apply on checkbox?

Tags: html, css, checkbox

Let say I have following class into my general.css. this css has been applied on default.aspx.

In general.css there is class checkbox{ .... }
on default.aspx I have one checkbox with

```
<input type='checkbox' />
```

so when page loads class checkbox applied on my checkbox. I want to prevent to apply checkbox class on this

checkbox. condition is I can't change general.css also I can't remove reference of general.css from default.aspx.
only can do with input tag.

Comment: Any CSS to show us ?

Comment: override `checkbox{ .... }` in default.aspx

Comment: Have a google for css specificity or remove the class that is styling the checkbox from the input.  If you can't change the stylesheet then either add another stylesheet below it to override it, or use inline styles

Answer (score 1):

checkbox is not a class,

.checkbox is a class, notice the dot in front of "checkbox"

to limit the CSS styling to a specific element, you can use ID.

```
<input type='checkbox' id='checkboxWithStyle'/>
```

in the CSS:

```
#checkboxWithStyle{
  background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have css as follows:

```
input[type='checkbox'] {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Add another class:

```
input[type='checkbox'].notdefault {
    border: none;
}
```

Then change your input:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="notdefault" />
```

The new class can be in another css file or embedded in the aspx page.